# How to use particular gem version on irb?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

On my machine, I've following Selenium WebDriver versions:

`selenium-webdriver (2.35.1, 2.35.0, 2.33.0, 2.32.1)`

While executing selenium commands on irb, I want to use `selenium-webdriver 2.35.0`  All api related to Selenium Webdriver should use `selenium-webdriver 2.35.0`

How can I achieve this?

Something like `require 'selenium-webdriver 2.35.0'`? Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need a call to [`gem`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/gem) first:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '= 2.35.0'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Comment: The word `gem` is linked. I initially looked it up in the Pickaxe, where it's in para 15.5, section "Gems and Versions"